# How group values in Mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have query:

```
SELECT      p.`obj_id` , 
            p.`alt_name` , 
            o.`name`,
            p.`id`,
            oc.`text_val`,
            oc.`float_val` 
FROM        `cms3_hierarchy` p 
LEFT JOIN   `cms3_objects` o 
    ON      p.`obj_id` = o.`id` 
LEFT JOIN   `cms3_object_content` oc 
    ON      p.`obj_id` = oc.`obj_id` 
WHERE       (oc.`field_id` = 221 OR oc.`field_id` = 248 ) 
    AND     (p.`rel`=903687) LIMIT 0,50
```

But answer like this:

```
obj_id name id 221  248
1      first    2    null
1      first    null  3
```

Well, i have one obj_id with different values.
But for me this is look like this:

```
obj_id name id 221  248
1      first    2    3
```

How to do this?

Comment: That query won't give those results - that said, what's wrong with a simple `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Conditions on the right table of a `LEFT JOIN` should be specified only inside the `ON` clause, when they are in the `WHERE` clause, the join automatically turns into an `INNER JOIN` because of `NULL` comparison. 

Also, use `IN()` to compare the same column to multiple values instead of `OR` . I also used `MAX()` to group the rows into one row,  so :

```
SELECT p.obj_id , p.alt_name , o.name,p.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN oc.field_id = 221 THEN oc.text_val END) as col_221,
       MAX(CASE WHEN oc.field_id = 1123 THEN oc.text_val END) as col_1123,
       MAX(oc.float_val)
FROM cms3_hierarchy p 
LEFT JOIN cms3_objects o 
 ON p.obj_id = o.id 
LEFT JOIN cms3_object_content oc
 ON p.obj_id = oc.obj_id  and oc.field_id in(221,248,1123)
WHERE p.rel=903687 
LIMIT 0,50
GROUP BY p.obj_id , p.alt_name , o.name,p.id
```

Comment: No this is same query!

Comment: This work! But if i wont use more one field (221,248, 1123), then doesnt work!

Comment: The field with id 1123 have a text_val - column, as field 221

Comment: What do you expect to get when 3 values? How many values do you want? Give me something generic! @muldy

Comment: Now i want three values (221,248, 1123)
221 and 1123 - same coloumn - text_val